# Why do Automatic planetary transmissions have gear teeth cut on the outside of the ring gear?

Tags: automatic-transmission, part-identification, gears, drivetrain

it makes sense that there are teeth cut inside the ring gear since planet gears rotate around inside of the ring. However there are also gear teeth cut on the outside of the ring gear, i think they are there to mesh with the brake clutches somehow so when brake clutch is applied the ring will be held stationary. Is this true? If it is true i could not really imagine how these gear teeth would be helpful in the brake clutches stopping the ring from rotating since the brake clutches and the teeth on the outside of ring gear dont seem to be meshing. They look 90 degree to each other how can they mesh? For example in the pictures below circled in green is the teeth that im talking about on the outside of the ring gear.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't gear teeth. They are teeth which holds the assembly in place relative to the case. The case will have teeth in them as well.

**EDIT 1:**

Here's the best I could do as far as an image, but if you look at the front of the case (facing the camera), you can see the teeth in the case. While this isn't an *exact* match to the images you're showing, it is an example:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Here's a second example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much